# Doctrine, как посчитать кол-во записей с join?

Tags: php, doctrine2

Есть некий запрос на получение данных (запрос сокращен для удобства):

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(['record', 'type'])
            ->from(Record::class, 'record')
            ->leftJoin('record.type', 'type');

$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('type.alias', 'news'));
$qb->addCriteria($criteria);

$query = $qb->getQuery();

$query->getScalarResult();
```

Мне нужно проделать пожалуй тоже самое, только получить кол-во записей скалярным числом.
Понятно, что вариант с count($query->getScalarResult()) не подходит по оптимизации.

Подскажите, как можно подсчитать кол-во записей, учитывая join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо переписать Ваш DQL запрос: нужно определить по какому полю будем считать количество записей - предполагаю, что в Вашем случае, Вы хотите подсчитать к-во record с определенным type.

Тогда DQL будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('COUNT(record.id)')
        ->from(Record::class, 'record')
        ->leftJoin('record.type', 'type')
        ->groupBy('type.alias');

    $countRes = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

Также, если Вам важно именно оптимизировать этот участок, можно использовать `NativeQuery` (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) - через него будет эффективнее, но придется пожертвовать тем, что SQL будете писать в терминах хранилища данных, а не ООП-модели приложения. Какой вариант Вам предпочтительнее, выбирайте из особенностей приложения.

Лично я бы вынес метод получения кол-ва записей по тэгу в отдельный метод репозитория (что то вроде `RecordsRepository#countByTag(TagInterface $tag) : int`), и инкапсулировал бы эту логику внутри этого метода, чтобы она не растекалась по приложению.